# Is it possible to convert .vdi or .vhd into OS cloning images?

Tags: virtualbox, disk-cloning, acronis-trueimage

I think the question isn't so clear. I'm asking if it's possible to convert Virtual Hard Disk files (.vdi, .vhd, etc., **including snapshots**) into Acronis Images, so I could emulate the system, set the state I want and then clone it into a physical machine.

Comment: I don't have a full answer here, but some hints: for virtualbox files, you can use the vboxmanage program with the clonehd option to convert a VDI or whatever to a raw data file, which perhaps you can then figure out how to convert into an Acronis image.

Comment: Yes;  Certain Acronis products can do this.